# Get property by path

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have an following object:

```
var obj = {
    property: [{key:"value1"},{key:"value2"}]
}
```

And I have following string `property[0].key`

How can I obtain `value2` using this string inside code?

Basicly I want to de something like this `obj["property[1].key"]`

If string have only dots, I can use following code:

```
function get_property_by_string(object, string){
    return string.split(".").reduce(function(obj, key) {
        return obj[key];
    }, object);
}
```

But with array this code doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: We need more context. What possible strings can you have ?

Comment: `obj.property[1].key` ??

Comment: @mithunsatheesh yes, but I have it as a string. I can't use use it this way obj["property[1].key"]

Comment: `var p = "property"; console.log( obj[p][1].key )` ?

Comment: you can use eval(obj.property[1].key) but it's dangerous function

Comment: `for(var index in obj.property) { index.key; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use the Eval() function
which takes a string content and evaluate it as a command.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: Is it any chance to avoid eval? Or is it only easy way?

Comment: I guess you are concerned of Code injections? 
Can you specify your Goal, and constraints , maybe we can suggest an alternative way...

Comment: the other way is to parse the string... 
not that hard to do... but will take about 25 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your property is stored as a string is not an issue. access the property of an object as such:

```
var obj = { 'key_a' : [{key:'value', otherkey: 'other value' }] },
    property = "key_a";

 obj[property][0].otherkey; // outputs "other value"
```

Avoid eval() if you can, it will only add overhead to your program and its usage is considered bad practice by some.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know where is exactly this property located. I have only string.

Comment: You don't need to know where the property of an Object is located, you access it via its key (a string), but perhaps I have misunderstood the question? :)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating 'property' as an array, so you should be able to access it directly. I've tested the following code locally on Chrome and it appears to work fine.

```
var obj = {
    property: [{key:"value1"},{key:"value2"}]
}

function test()
{
    alert(obj.property[0].key); // shows value1
    alert(obj.property[1].key); // shows value2
}
```